# Getting Balance from Service provider

Tags: android

Im trying to create a application to check balance and alert the prepaid user if the balance is less than certain amount say < Rs.100

So i check the balance using the code

```
     Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123#"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

But the reply from the service provider doesnot come as SMS but it appearrs as toast message.How can i retrieve the value from the message and use it in my application??

Comment: i dont think its possible to intercept that kinda event and extract info is there any app doing so ?

Comment: That's not possible unless telecom provider itself releases some API. Also you would require APIs from every possible provider. In India list grows every 2-3 years.